# Combining three similar Pandas datasets, keeping original values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have three similar data sets given by the lines below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Michael', 'Samantha', 'Jimmy'], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M'], 'Mon': [0,1,2], 'Tue': [0,3,5], 'Wed': [0,5,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Michael', 'Samantha', 'Jimmy'], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M'], 'Mon': [1,2,4], 'Tue': [2,3,5], 'Wed': [1,4,5]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Michael', 'Samantha', 'Jimmy'], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M'], 'Mon': [5,4,0], 'Tue': [4,6,5], 'Wed': [1,7,6]})
```

Each data frame, respectively, appears as such:

```py
>>> df1
       Name Gender  Mon  Tue  Wed
0   Michael      M    0    0    0
1  Samantha      F    1    3    5
2     Jimmy      M    2    5    3
>>> df2
       Name Gender  Mon  Tue  Wed
0   Michael      M    1    2    1
1  Samantha      F    2    3    4
2     Jimmy      M    4    5    5
>>> df3
df3
       Name Gender  Mon  Tue  Wed
0   Michael      M    5    4    1
1  Samantha      F    4    6    7
2     Jimmy      M    0    5    6
```

Is there any way to create a resultant data frame that combines the numbers into one data frame? A result would appear as:

```py
       Name Gender        Mon     Tue     Wed
0   Michael      M    [0,1,5] [0,2,4] [0,1,1]
1  Samantha      F    [1,2,4] [3,3,6] [5,4,7]
2     Jimmy      M    [2,4,0] [5,5,5] [3,5,6]
```

The order of the data would have to be maintained. The first item in the list doesn't necessarily have to come from the first dataset (`df1`), but I would like to always know where the number from the first dataset lands so that I can pull that specific value out of the combined data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `concat` then `groupby`

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).set_index(['Name','Gender']).groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list).reset_index()
Out[20]: 
       Name Gender        Mon        Tue        Wed
0     Jimmy      M  [2, 4, 0]  [5, 5, 5]  [3, 5, 6]
1   Michael      M  [0, 1, 5]  [0, 2, 4]  [0, 1, 1]
2  Samantha      F  [1, 2, 4]  [3, 3, 6]  [5, 4, 7]
```